# How to have same CBV class hierarchy in two URL prefixes with separate superclass dispatch() methods in Django

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I have a (CBV) superclasses (inheriting from Django's `View` and a mixin) and multiple subclasses for that.

I need to have the exact same functionality implemented in all the subclasses, but the actual parent class is going to be completely different except for the fact that will inherit also from Django's `View`.

So in effect I need to have the same subclass functionality available via:

1. different URLs (or actually different URL *prefix* and same set of URLs)
2. different `dispatch()` method (common for all subclasses but different for both sets)

What is the most sensible way of doing this?

**EDIT**:
Actually, I think I can solve this by changing this in an easy way

Change `dispatch()` so that it calls `dispatchA()` if URL was `/a/...` and `dispatchB()` if URL was `/b/.../`

Now the question is: __Is it OK to use the same `pattern(...)` twice in django `urlpatterns()` with different prefix.

For extra credit, any idea how to add a kwarg (like `b = True`) to the latter pattern.

Comment: I suggest raising a new question, as it's something totally new.

Comment: Will do that. I also would suggest you not to down vote questions out of spite :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the delegation pattern to handle to common aspects of your classes.

A mixin class should also be fine for this, if you can avoid the diamond shape inheritance pattern.

Comment: Diamond shaped inheritance pattern is the exact reason why I'm asking the question here. You might have put me on right track by mentioning delegation, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'll get flamed for this, supposed anti-pattern, but I use multiple inheritance in these cases and treat the shared "child" as a mix-in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think u should do a sub-class in this case.

The sub-class is used when the two classes has the 'is-a' relationship. e.g. 'square' is a 'shape', so 'square' could be subclass of 'shape'.

by sub-classing, u normally want the subclass to inherit the **internal state description** of the superclass.

if u just want to re-use some of the functions, I suggest u should do some refactorings, and extract those common functions into a helper class.

Comment: -1 for bad spelling and assuming that I don't want to inherit the internal state description

Comment: So you want one sub-class to inherit the internal state descriptions of two super classes? And you still believe there is a design pattern for that?